How can I remove tack strip from cement without leaving holes for the nails?
Kind of a combination of this and this question, I'm removing carpet from a basement.  Is it possible to remove carpet tackstrip (secured with hardened nails) from cement without making holes or with making minimal holes?
The normal recommendation for removing tack strip is to hit at the side of the strip (under the strip) where the nails are until the nails come out.  Kind of jar them out. I tried various ways to do this (flat end shovel, flooring shovel/scraper, prybar hammered, ramming prybar into the wood, etc.) and they all seem to make about a quarter sized hole with each nail.  (Prying "up" on the strips makes about a half dollar size hole and makes cement go flying everywhere).  I'd like to not leave the holes in there, just for completeness sake and not having to worry about something heavy (like a furniture leg), ever.
I can fill that with cement, but curious if there are other ways to avoid needing to fill the holes?  There are use cases where this is an interesting question, like with smaller jobs or with terrazo flooring, less damage (and less work--i.e. mixing, and tools) is desired.  Or for those of us who have never done cement work, it's a bit daunting and requires some extra hardware, especially with mixing involved.
I will be covering the concrete with fairly thin LVP (4.5mm + 1.5mm pad).

You should be able to pick up a tub of concrete patch from Home Depot or whatnot for under $20. Pop the strips out and patch the holes. That's pretty much the best, quickest, and easiest solution.

Yeah I was initially scared to do this because my home depot only carried "cures in 24 hour" type stuff, but I eventually found some powder (CementAll) that cured in 1 hr [though has to be constantly sprayed] so I took the plunge and learned to mix... :)

Any way you get those nails out is going to leave a scar on the concrete.  A previous answer to this question would leave the spot flush with no damage to the concrete floor however, it also leaves a portion of those nails.
What are you going to do with the floor once the carpet is removed?  If it will be unfinished and if you take the time to effectively polish the nails flush - you've got raw steel which will rust if it gets damp.
If you plan to put some sort of flooring over the concrete, you could do as I've done in the past - simply ignore the spots where the nails were popped out, it's covered by whatever the new flooring is.  In my case, that was laminate with an underpad.
If you've never seen what's under that carpet, it might not be a nicely finished concrete floor.  My current unfinished basement has areas where the original builder spilled some white paint as well as a few other blemishes.
I see where the originator of this question lives in Utah which is a dry part of the USA.  In other parts of the USA as well as many other places in the world, houses are sometimes attacked by termites.  Typical treatment in the Southeast portion of the USA sometimes includes drilling holes every few feet in the basement concrete floor, injecting a termiticide then patching the holes.  Concrete patching material is readily available.  Your nail holes are much smaller than that seen in basements after termite treatment but - still, it's a matter of patching the concrete damaged by removing the nails. Such patching can be made quite smooth.
I'd not leave the polished edges of nails exposed.

It'll be replaced with LVP (4.5mm + 1.5mm pad) FWIW...I have heard that laminate is a little more forgiving to divets since it's thicker(though it indents more easily?), I was kind afraid my thin pad wouldn't be thick enough to fill the divets :)

It's not a matter of the pad filling the divots. It's a matter of the product spanning them, which almost any laminate will do. Skim fill anything bigger than say an inch across and move on with life.

There is no reasonable way to remove tack strips without getting divots. Yes, there may be a process, but it doesn't make sense to spend 2 hours to prevent divots, when filling them can be done in 20 minutes.
You said you were covering the concrete  with LVP. ( Added that to the question from your comment.)
With LVP, there isn't a need to fill the divots from tack strip nails, since they are so close to the walls. Divots out in the open can be filled with 
patch  and leveler .

Also, any holes are gonna be too small (unless your tack strips have massive nails) for LVP to even flex on.

Yeah I've done it that way before, but I wanted to do a "solid, high quality" job and to avoid worry of potential problems if something heavy is placed over a hole (furniture peg?). I'm using cheap lvp :) An occasional hole may be wider than a quarter (though tends to be more shallow? My cement may be more brittle than most?). There are some tack strips not against the wall (transition from living room to kitchen threshold)...and for some odd I had two rows of tack strip so it came out farther from the wall.  Wishing I had to do only one job instead of two.  Just trying to give more context :)

@Huesmann, it's common for tack strip nails (which are thicker in tack strip made for concrete) to blow out the surface of the concrete. It's almost never just a nail-sized hole that remains. While still not an issue for most flooring, it could be for thinner varieties of vinyl, for example.

@isherwood I'm aware of that.  What I'm saying is that the size of the holes (blowouts, if you want to call them that)—maybe the size of a penny?—are too small to affect LVP, unless it's really superthin LVP.  OP said they are using LVP, so...

One option is to use an oscillating tool.  It takes about 1 "high quality" head for 20 nails or so (since they're hardened), but it cuts it perfectly flush to the floor.
I did not use this method cause of the cost of blades, I had tons of nails to cut.  It also seems to take awhile to do the cuts, but I have heard of people doing it (maybe a higher quality blade would speed it up?) and it's a nice flush cut.  I didn't do enough nails to know if there are other caveats (does it "shake" out neighbor nails, leaving a hole, if you don't remove the wood first [if you have to remove the wood first that takes awhile and is tricky]?  Is it slow?  I'd estimate this is about 3x longer than just filling with cement)

Another fairly common one is to use an "angle grinder" and grind down the nails.
You can cut off the heads of nails first to decrease amount of dust.  A "depressed center" cut-off blade can help that cut get lower, but not all the way flush.
It does leave a tiny hole of collateral grinding (i.e. in the cement) if you want to get it truly flush. I find that straight down from the top leaves the smallest collateral hole.  Like perpendicular.  Using a "new" grinding wheel with a still-flat edge might help as well for that particular angle.  Or might not be necessary.
Not sure if need to remove the carpet wood strip first but I did.  A wood chisel might work, or possibly oscillating saw.
This does take some TLC, I'd estimate about 2x the time of filling with cement.

Another way is to try to "carefully" remove each nail.  By tapping it in first (got holes down to like dime size), or by hitting a claw hammer claw through the middle of the wood so that it has leverage down while you're pulling it up.  Works pretty well but takes a long time.
Cutting them off with a "nipper" or "dremel metal cutter" don't make it perfectly flush, but maybe good enough in some instances.
